# AWS CodeBuild no matching artifacts found error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Tring to build asp.net application using codebuild and getting `no matching artifacts found error`.
Any way we can check where this artifacts getting created on the build agent?

[image]

version: 0.2

```
phases:
  install:


  pre_build:
    commands:
     - New-Item -ItemType Junction -Path C:\Src -Value $Env:CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
     - cd C:\Src  
     - nuget.exe restore

  build:
    commands:
      - echo Executing Build Phase
      - echo build started on `date`
      - msbuild .\ASPWebApp\ASPWebApp.csproj /p:outdir=.\build_output
    finally:
      - echo Executing build finally


artifacts:
    files:
        - .\build_output\**\*
    name: newbucket26
```

Comment: Could you paste the code as text, instead of a screenshot?

Comment: added text. Also Removed unnecessary commands in the text.

Comment: If you have logs enabled, CB produces lots of log data. Have you inspected that for any errors?

Comment: Path of `build_output` folder should be .\ASPWebApp\build_output. Inside this folder .dll files are there. When i build same project using visual studio i get different files and here i am getting different files. Is there anything missing in my build command?

Comment: When i did locl build `_PublishedWebsites` is getting created and inside that all the artifacts present. But on CodeBuild no `_PublishedWebsites` folder is getting created. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue.
AWS codebuild default windows build agent does not support asp.net framework, it only supports .net core framework. So to build asp.net application we need to use a custom docker image provided by Microsoft.